# file doesn't work when javascript moves to external file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying out socket.io and downloaded its GitHub [project](https://github.com/socketio/chat-example).

It worked fine, but when I tried to move the inline js code to an external file, it stopped working. Why is that so? What did I do wrong?

In its index.html file it has:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I tried to move the inline code to an external js file. I copied everything between the "script" tag and put it in a file I named "chat.js". The index.html file and chat.js are on the same level.

So now the same part in the html file looks like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="chat.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and the chat.js file looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure you have given the correct path in <script src >

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: You are defining the `socket` variable in a local scope within the function.
Try to move socket out of the function in your external file.

Comment: @FabZbi and why would that matter? Why would it make a difference when the OP moves it into an external script?

Comment: @epascarello you're right doesn't make any sense..
But why are you taking the `socket.js`in the html from the local path and in the external example from a CDN? Maybe there is the issue?

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov there are no errors in the console. however, when i click the button on the form, the link goes to http://localhost:3000/? with a "?" at the end

Comment: @MonikaMangal yeah, it seems like so :/ I tried putting a "/" infront (src="/chat.js") that didn't work either. The files are on the same level, so it shouldn't need the "/" right?

Comment: yes, if the files are on the same level then you don't need '/'

Comment: out of curiosity, on your index.html page if you type <script src= do you see your external js file in the list or can you browse to it if you choose Pick URL?

Comment: Look at the network tab, is it a 404?

Comment: @epascarello, yes i just looked at the inspect page, it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" Why?

Comment: Try adding './' before chat.js, like './chat.js'

Comment: @MonikaMangal that didn't work :/

Comment: why? well sounds like the file is not there? unclear why..... what happens when you type the url to the file directly in the browser?

Comment: @epascarello you mean like "http://localhost:3000/chat.js"? it says "Cannot GET /chat.js"

Comment: so it is in the same level as your index file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion, you would have to add the following to your index.js to serve static files in Express.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(require('express').static(__dirname)); // Add this to serve static files
```

Else, it wouldn't able to find where is chat.js thus getting 404 error.

You can read more about it [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).